# Copy last 30 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that copies the range A2:AJ30 and pastes it below.
Is there a way then to change this so each time that i run the macro, it takes the last 31 rows that are in the sheet rather that always the first one?
See marco code:

```
    If .Range("C1").Value < 1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Please enter valid number of at least 1 copy"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    copies = .Range("C1").Value
    
        For i = 1 To copies
        
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
            .Range("A" & lastRow & ":AJ" & lastRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
            
            .Range("A2:AJ30").Copy
            
            .Paste .Range("A" & lastRow)
    
        Next i
    
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Template copied " & copies & " time(s)."

End Sub
```

I have not tried anything yet as i'm not sure how to do this

Screen shots:
[image: file when you open]

[image: Once duplicated]

Comment: Please share the preceding (missing) code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code is close to finish.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim Copies As Long, lastRow As Long, startRow As Long
    Dim srcRng As Range, i As Long
    Const ROW_CNT = 30  ' Copy 30 rows
    Const COL_CNT = 36  ' Col A:AJ
    With ActiveSheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        If .Range("C1").Value < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number of at least 1 copy"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Copies = .Range("C1").Value
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        startRow = lastRow - ROW_CNT + 1
        If startRow < 1 Then startRow = 1
        Set srcRng = .Range("A" & startRow & ":AJ" & lastRow)
        For i = 1 To Copies
            .Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(1, COL_CNT).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            srcRng.Copy .Range("A" & lastRow + 2)
            lastRow = lastRow + ROW_CNT + 1
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Template copied " & Copies & " time(s)."
End Sub
```

---

**Update:** Get `Copies` from the cell which is one row above the copied data range (30 rows) and in column C.

- Below snippet copies `3 rows` for testing. Please modify as needed.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim Copies As Long, lastRow As Long, startRow As Long
    Dim srcRng As Range, i As Long
    Const ROW_CNT = 3  ' For testing, modify as needed (30 rows)
    Const COL_CNT = 36  ' Col A:AJ
    With ActiveSheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        startRow = lastRow - ROW_CNT + 1
        If startRow < 2 Then
            MsgBox "Data rows are less than 30"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Copies = .Cells(startRow - 1, "C").Value
        If Copies < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter valid number of at least 1 copy"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srcRng = .Range("A" & startRow & ":AJ" & lastRow)
        For i = 1 To Copies
            .Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(1, COL_CNT).Interior.ColorIndex = 1
            srcRng.Copy .Range("A" & lastRow + 2)
            lastRow = lastRow + ROW_CNT + 1
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Template copied " & Copies & " time(s)."
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @taller, thanks. The macro works except it always takes the value (number of copies to make) form the very first section, not the most recent created ?

Comment: @ad_aus83 How to determine `Copies`? What's the location of cell?

Comment: So in the first section, there is the macro button (B:1), and then next to it a cell to enter the number of copies we wish to have (C:1)

Comment: `Copies = .Range("C1").Value` the code gets the number of copies from C1. What's wrong with the code? What's `the most recent created`? You may edit your post to show the detail if it's difficult to explain in comment section.

Comment: it works for the first one, but then say if i duplcaite it, then i tryto duplicate from the second one, it uses the value set in the first one.

Comment: the second one becomes C:32.. and so on.

Comment: `Copies` should come from the cell which is one row above the data range (30 rows) and in column C. Is it right?

Comment: the data is 30 rows, but then when you duplicate it add 1 row (black line) to separate them, so the next data starts at row 32, next is 63.
So i want it to come from the last data set please.

Comment: Assume C1 = 2, the first run copies rows(2:31) twice. The last data is on row 93. The blank seperated rows are in row 32 and 63. Now, the last 30 rows are rows(64:93). For the 2nd run, do you want to get the copies from C32?

Comment: Something isnt working right now.
Its now duplicating just the last 3 rows 500x?

Comment: Please have a look on the comments in my code. You need change `Const ROW_CNT = 3` to `30`. Is my screenshot what you are looking for if we ignore how many rows are copied?

Comment: ah ok sorry, 30 didn't work, 29 does but doesn't put the macro button and line in with the new duplicate. 
also when i type 2 in the field, it errors 'Please enter valid number of at least 1 copy'

Comment: `copies the range A2:AJ30` macro button is not in the range. What is the location of the field?

Comment: The macro button is B1 and the entry field (to enter the number of duplicates needed) is C1

Comment: I'm confused. Please edit your post to share a screenshot. It's helpful to understand what's the difference between the 1st run vs the 2nd run.

Comment: Thanks @taller, ive added the screen shots of when i open the doc, and then when i make a duplication.

Comment: Change two lines  `Const ROW_CNT = 29` `Copies = .Cells(1, "C").Value`.

Comment: Done, but its still not adding the copy template Macro button line?
Its adding the correct duplicate (the last data set) but i would like it to also duplicate the macro button line each time also, so i dont have  to scroll all the way to the top each time to duplicate, especially once i have a lot of data sets

Comment: Is copied button on the black row?

Comment: No, i checked and there is nothing in the black row?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to copy the button. Try freeze top row: select cell A1, view > Freeze Panes > Freeze Top Row. The first row is always on. Users can click the button anytime.

Comment: Ah, yeah good idea! I think that will solve the issue. Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it @taller

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. If I understood what you were trying to do correctly, this should do what you want.

Note: I prefer to use row/column (R1C1) notation in my VBA scripts rather than the traditional A1 notation. Thus `Range("B5") = Cells(5, 2)`

### Version 1

This version, when making multiple copies, takes the first `COPY_ROWS` rows and duplicates them multiple times.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyLast()
On Error GoTo Err_CopyLast

    Dim i As Long              'loop iterator
    Dim copies As Long         'number of copies to make
    Dim lastDataRow As Long    'last row of data in the sheet
    Dim startCopyRow As Long   'first row to copy
    Dim endCopyRow As Long     'last row to copy
    
    Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1   'column A
    Const LAST_COL As Long = 36   'column AJ
    Const COPY_ROWS As Long = 30  'number of rows to copy
    
    'do not update the screen while working
    'this makes the code run faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With ActiveSheet
        'get the number of copies to make
        copies = .Cells(1, 3).Value
        
        'verify the user selected at least one copy
        If copies < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid number of at least 1 copy"
            GoTo Exit_CopyLast
        End If
        
        'start from last row of column B and
        'move upwards to find last row with data
        lastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'set the rows to be copied
        startCopyRow = lastDataRow - COPY_ROWS + 1
        endCopyRow = lastDataRow
                
        'make the copies
        For i = 1 To copies
            'make a black row to separate the existing data
            'from the copy about to be added
            With .Range(.Cells(lastDataRow + 1, FIRST_COL), _
                        .Cells(lastDataRow + 1, LAST_COL))
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 1    'black
            End With
            
            'copy the last COPY_ROWS of data
            .Range(.Cells(startCopyRow, FIRST_COL), _
                   .Cells(endCopyRow, LAST_COL)).Copy
            
            'paste the copied data
            .Paste .Cells(lastDataRow + 2, 1)
            
            'update the lastDataRow for the next iteration
            lastDataRow = lastDataRow + COPY_ROWS + 1
        Next i
    
        'deselect the copied cells
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        'put the cursor in the last row of data
        .Cells(lastDataRow, 1).Activate
    End With
  
    MsgBox "Template copied " & copies & " time(s)."

Exit_CopyLast:
    'ensure screen updating gets turned back on
    'regardless of if any error occurs
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
    
Err_CopyLast:
    'display the error information
    MsgBox Err.Number + ": " + Err.Description, _
           vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
           "Error!"
    'exit normally
    GoTo Exit_CopyLast
End Sub
```

### Version 2

This version, when making multiple copies, always copies the last `COPY_ROWS` rows from the bottom which means that on copy 2, it is copying the rows that were created by copy 1, etc.

```
Public Sub CopyLast()

    Dim i As Long              'loop iterator
    Dim copies As Long         'number of copies to make
    Dim lastDataRow As Long    'last row of data in the sheet
    Dim startCopyRow As Long   'first row to copy
    
    Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1   'column A
    Const LAST_COL As Long = 36   'column AJ
    Const COPY_ROWS As Long = 30  'number of rows to copy
    
    With ActiveSheet
        'get the number of copies to make
        copies = .Cells(1, 3).Value
        
        'verify the user selected at least one copy
        If copies < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid number of at least 1 copy"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'make the copies
        For i = 1 To copies
            'start from last row of column B and
            'move upwards to find last row with data
            lastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            
            'make a black row to separate the existing data
            'from the copy about to be added
            With .Range(.Cells(lastDataRow + 1, FIRST_COL), _
                        .Cells(lastDataRow + 1, LAST_COL))
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 1    'black
            End With
            
            'set the first row to be copied
            startCopyRow = lastDataRow - COPY_ROWS + 1
        
            'copy the last COPY_ROWS of data
            .Range(.Cells(startCopyRow, FIRST_COL), _
                   .Cells(lastDataRow, LAST_COL)).Copy
            
            'paste the copied data
            .Paste .Cells(lastDataRow + 2, 1)
        Next i
    
        'deselect the copied cells
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        'put the cursor in the last row of data
        .Cells(lastDataRow, 1).Activate
    End With
  
    MsgBox "Template copied " & copies & " time(s)."

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulR, looks like its working with a couple of exceptions.
Its not duplicating multiple if we put a number in the value cell like it was before?
Secondly, previously it would duplicate it and we would see it show up instantly.
Now the screen goes white and we don't see anything until we click ok on the message box. Not end of world but different from before.

Comment: just to add to that, i just found that the number of duplicates does work, but it always takes it from the very first one, not a duplicate!

Comment: @ad_aus83 You are not seeing it change in real time because of the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. That is what that setting does, it does not update the screen while the code runs. I included it because it was in your original code, you can remove all references and then things will update in real-time.

Comment: The duplicating behavior was my misunderstanding of what you wanted. I was not sure if you wanted to duplicate the original multiple times, or just keep duplicating the last 30 rows.

Comment: @ad_aus83 I just added version 2 which should do what you are describing. I also removed the error handing and screen updating disabling code. Overall a much simpler script.

Comment: Thanks Paul. so yeah i want it to duplicate the last one created. WHich it was doing, but the macro in the last one duplicated only will duplicate 1 more no matter how many you enter enter in the feild. You have to go up to the top one (first one) and enter the number to then get it to add multiple. if that makes sense?

Comment: tried the new one and it seems to still be doing the same thing.

Comment: thanks for your help with this. I have the macro running almost as id like with the exception of 1 thing. When i ask it to duplicate, there is a box beside the button on my sheet where i enter a number value. So if i want it to duplicate 3 ties i enter 3 and then press the button.
Thi works for the first one, but then when i try on one of the duplicated sections, it only ever duplicates 1x?

ill add the macro as it currently is as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Bottom Rows

[image]

```vb
Sub CopyBottomRows()
     
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DATA_COLUMNS As String = "A:AJ"
    Const COPIES_CELL As String = "C1"
    Const LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "B"
    Const MAX_COPIES As Long = 10
    Const COPY_ROWS As Long = 5
    Const EMPTY_ROWS As Long = 1
    Const EMPTY_ROW_COLOR_INDEX As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
        
    Dim ccell As Range: Set ccell = ws.Range(COPIES_CELL)
    Dim Copies As Variant: Copies = ccell.Value
    
    Dim IsValidInteger As Boolean
    
    If VarType(Copies) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        If Copies = CLng(Copies) Then ' is an integer
            If Copies >= 1 Or Copies <= MAX_COPIES Then IsValidInteger = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not IsValidInteger Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an integer between 1 and " & MAX_COPIES _
            & " in cell """ & COPIES_CELL & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim LastRow As Long:
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LAST_ROW_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If LastRow < COPY_ROWS Then
        MsgBox "There are only " & LastRow & " rows!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    Dim lrrg As Range: Set lrrg = ws.Columns(DATA_COLUMNS).Rows(LastRow)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = lrrg.Offset(1 - COPY_ROWS).Resize(COPY_ROWS)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To Copies
        lrrg.Offset(1).Resize(EMPTY_ROWS) _
            .Interior.ColorIndex = EMPTY_ROW_COLOR_INDEX
        crg.Copy lrrg.Offset(EMPTY_ROWS + 1)
        Set lrrg = lrrg.Offset(COPY_ROWS + EMPTY_ROWS)
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Template copied " & Copies & " time" _
        & IIf(Copies = 1, "", "s") & ".", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@PaulR
this is the current macro that has the duplicate issue:

Public Sub CopyLast()

```
Dim i As Long              'loop iterator
Dim copies As Long         'number of copies to make
Dim lastDataRow As Long    'last row of data in the sheet
Dim startCopyRow As Long   'first row to copy

Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1   'column A
Const LAST_COL As Long = 36   'column AJ
Const COPY_ROWS As Long = 30  'number of rows to copy

With ActiveSheet
    'get the number of copies to make
    copies = .Cells(1, 3).Value
    
    'verify the user selected at least one copy
    If copies < 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid number of at least 1 copy"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'make the copies
    For i = 1 To copies
        'start from last row of column B and
        'move upwards to find last row with data
        lastDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        'make a black row to separate the existing data
        'from the copy about to be added
        With .Range(.Cells(lastDataRow + 1, FIRST_COL), _
                    .Cells(lastDataRow + 1, LAST_COL))
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 1    'black
        End With
        
        'set the first row to be copied
        startCopyRow = lastDataRow - COPY_ROWS + 1
    
        'copy the last COPY_ROWS of data
        .Range(.Cells(startCopyRow, FIRST_COL), _
               .Cells(lastDataRow, LAST_COL)).Copy
        
        'paste the copied data
        .Paste .Cells(lastDataRow + 2, 1)
    Next i

    'deselect the copied cells
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'put the cursor in the last row of data
    .Cells(lastDataRow, 1).Activate
End With

MsgBox "Template copied " & copies & " time(s)."
```

End Sub